# Why I cannot use array index decrement when using a another array value in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, insertion-sort

This is a simple code for Insertion Sort in Java. I tried reducing the lines of my Java code. But it cannot be done with this issue. I want to know why it cannot be done.

*Code that I have tried (error happens in line number 9)*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InsertionSortModified {
    public static int[] insertionSort(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            int pos = i;
            while (pos > 0 && arr[pos-1] > temp)
                arr[pos--] = arr[pos-1];
            arr[pos] = temp;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int elementarr[] = new int[5];

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            elementarr[j] = scnr.nextInt();
        
        elementarr = insertionSort(elementarr);
        for (int j = 0; j < elementarr.length; j++)
            System.out.print(elementarr[j] + " ");
    }
}
```

*Error showing in the command window*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at InsertionSortModified.insertionSort(InsertionSortModified.java:9)
        at InsertionSortModified.main(InsertionSortModified.java:22)
```

*Program is working when the code modified to like this. (Line number 8 to 11)*

```
            while (pos > 0 && arr[pos-1] > temp) {
                arr[pos] = arr[pos-1];
                pos--;
            }
```

Why I cannot use

```
arr[pos--] = arr[pos-1];
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Please add the complete stack trace.

Comment: I have edited the question with the error.

Comment: Postdecrement means decrementing after getting the value, not after execution of a line, so `arr[pos--] = arr[pos];` would be your one-liner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what the problem is. Step by step execution of the code is here.

Line number 9:

When `i == 2`, `pos == 2`. At the line 9 execution order is like this.

1. At initially first execution if the while loop, `arr[2] = arr[pos-1]`.
2. Positioning the array index 2. But after positioning `pos` is decreasing to `pos == 1`.
3. Then line becomes to this `arr[2] = arr[1-1]` means `arr[2] = arr[0]`.
4. After that still `while` loop is true.
5. Then the second execution of the while loop at initially `arr[1] = arr[pos-1]`.
6. Then positioning the array index 1. But after positioning `pos` is decreasing to `pos == 0`.
7. Then line becomes to this `arr[1] = arr[0-1]` means `arr[1] = arr[-1]`.
8. So error happens in here. (`ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`).

Corrected code is like this. (Line number 9)

```
arr[pos--] = arr[pos];
```

or

```
arr[pos] = arr[--pos];
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to do

```
arr[pos--] = arr[pos-1];
```

and the value of `pos` is `1` then it decrements `pos` to 0, then in the second usage of `pos` you are making it `0 - 1`

Comment: `pos--` decreasing should be done after the execution of the line. No?

Comment: That should fix it.

Comment: I have inserted 7 13 1 8 3.
As per my knowledge,
At the stage of `i = 2`
`pos = 2`
`arr[pos--] = arr[pos-1]` and it should be likes this arr[2] = arr[1].
After changing the values of array `pos--` should be done. Am I wrong?

Comment: How do you ever get to `pos == 2`, it will fail when `pos == 1`

Comment: You are wrong. `pos--`will be executed before assigning `arr[pos] = arr[pos-1];`

Comment: If `pos == 2`, then you will effectively have `arr[2] = arr[1]`

Comment: `while (pos > 0 && arr[pos-1] > temp)` `{int abc = arr[pos-1]` `arr[pos--] = abc;}`

But it works like this.

Comment: Yes because you are doing `pos - 1` **before** `pos--`

Comment: Anyway, I have figured it out it's working like this. At the line `arr[pos--] = arr[pos-1];` array positioning the index 2 but `pos` decreasing and then again referring `pos-1`. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Code is working when it changed to `arr[pos--] = arr[pos];`

Answer (score 1):

In line 9 your decreasing the counter in the wrong order. The correct line is

```
`arr[pos] = arr[--pos];`
```

Here you're swapping the current value in arr[pos] for that in arr[pos-1] as you are decreasing the counter before using it. After, the pos value is already in the correct position to insert the 'temp' value

Comment: Yes. That's corret. Also works with `arr[pos--] = arr[pos];`.